# ODBC link between MS Access and qGIS .gpkg data?

Tags: sqlite, ms-access, qgis

I am an MS Office veteran with self-taught basic GIS skills (Tatuk Editor), including use of SQLite-based layers that link to MS Access. In the past few years I've been learning to use qGIS, and for the most part, the experience has been very positive.

What hasn't been so great in the qGIS learning curve is my attempt to link a qGIS-created geopackage layer (using the SQlite ODBC driver) to an MS Access application for the express purpose of editing and, ideally, for programmatic updating of attribute fields in existing records. Yes, the gpkg table will link, but unfortunately the connection is read-only. The problem apparently stems from an rtree rigger in the underlying geodatabase that won't allow the edited or updated records to be written /saved.

At the recommendation of a friend who is more highly versed in these technicalities, I tried to resolve the 'no gpkg editing' problem by adding spatialite .dll files to the system folder and appropriate extensions in the ODBC set up box, all without success. I next dumped the 32 bit version of my Office 365 software and transitioned to the 64 bit version, which fortunately didn't faze my existing documents, databases, etc. but had no effect whatsoever on the 'no gpkg editing' problem. At the end of the day, I'm no closer to achieving the desired solution, i.e. an editable connection between Access and the gpkg table.

Without going into immense detail of the various steps I've tried, I will stop here and give folks an opportunity to respond. I'm hopeful that someone reading this has not only encountered the 'no gpkg editing' problem when linking to a geopackage with MS Access, but has also learned how to resolve the issue. If you are that person, please explain the process as best possible. If it simply can't be done, I would appreciate knowing that, as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same exact problem. I downloaded the spatialite dlls and tried to put them in the same folder as the ODBC driver, and Sys32 other folders. No Dice. I tried using 32-bit and 64-bit driver, no dice. I tried the environment variable. No Dice.

I'm also an ArcGIS user who will miss being able to use Access Databases. Now that Pro can edit geopackages, we'd have a great option if we could edit the data in Access via ODBC. Frustrating!

Comment: Search for "ST_ IsEmpty" and you'll find several interesting discussions on topic of updating a geopackage table with ODBC connection. (Like this one:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/249787/geopackage-update-query-generates-an-error-no-such-function-st-isempty?noredirect=1&lq=1) I still think there must be a way, but if so, nobody is telling how to do it.